# Get Distinct Record of ID with Max Date and null date

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my table 1 and 2 which i use Left Join.
although it looks like it can be in one table.
Table 1 is like a master list where id can't be duplicate
so in Table 2 i add the name and date where id can be duplicate

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| id | Date    | Name           |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 1  | 5/25/17 | Monica Coleman |
| 1  | 5/26/17 | Kelsi Mines    |
| 2  |         |                |
| 3  | 5/9/17  | Vanessa Heart  |
| 4  | 5/8/17  | Ryan Evans     |
| 4  | 5/10/17 | Sharpay Evans  |
| 5  |         |                |
| 6  |         |                |
| 7  | 5/6/17  | Troy Bolton    |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

If I use this code...

```
SELECT P.id, R.DateAdded, R.Name FROM Table1 AS P LEFT JOIN Table2 AS R ON P.id=R.id WHERE ((([R.DateAdded])=(SELECT MAX(DateAdded) FROM R WHERE InventoryID = R.InventoryID)));
```

... then these results show...

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| id | Date    | Name           |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 1  | 5/26/17 | Kelsi Mines    |
| 3  | 5/9/17  | Vanessa Heart  |
| 4  | 5/10/17 | Sharpay Evans  |
| 7  | 5/6/17  | Troy Bolton    |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

But what I want the statement to return is...

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| id | Date    | Name           |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 1  | 5/26/17 | Kelsi Mines    |
| 2  |         |                |
| 3  | 5/9/17  | Vanessa Heart  |
| 4  | 5/10/17 | Sharpay Evans  |
| 5  |         |                |
| 6  |         |                |
| 7  | 5/6/17  | Troy Bolton    |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got my answer. i use Is Null

```
SELECT P.id, R.DateAdded, R.Name FROM Table1 AS P LEFT JOIN Table2 AS R ON P.id=R.id WHERE ((([R.DateAdded])=(SELECT MAX(DateAdded) FROM R WHERE InventoryID = R.InventoryID))) OR R.DateAdded IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

In most databases you would add the condition to the `ON` clause (or use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Neither is supported by MS Access.  So, use a subquery:

```
SELECT P.id, R.DateAdded, R.Name
FROM Table1 AS P LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT R.*
      FROM Table2 AS R
      WHERE R.DateAdded = (SELECT MAX(R2.DateAdded) FROM Table2 R2 WHERE R.InventoryID = R2.InventoryID)
     ) as R
     ON P.id = R.id
```

Comment: @elaine8s . . . Perhaps that was due to a typo in the `WHERE` clause.